# Method for api url: /something/{{id}}/something - Angular 6

Tags: angular

How can I create a method that will use this type of url in my service? 
This is my api url from swagger: `/api/campaign/{uuid}/activation/`, but I am not sure how can I use this in my service.

```
// i guess this has to change
private stopCampaignUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/campaign/activation/'; 

//this will put uuid at the end of url for now 
stopCampaign(uuid, stopModel: StopCampaignModel) {
        return this.http.put(`${this.stopCampaignUrl}${uuid}`, stopModel);
    }
```

Or maybe the best solution is to move the `{{uuid}}` to the end of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const startUrl = "/api/campaign/";
const endUrl = "/activation/";

return this.http.put(`${startUrl}${uuid}${endUrl}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider to write a separate method to get a url from uui and use it  in stopCampaign

```
private getCampageUrl(uuid){
   return environment.apiUrl + '/campaign/'+uuid+'/activation/'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have a function for you :

```
function stringFormat(format: string, ...args: string[]): string {
    return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, number) => {
        return typeof args[number] != "undefined" ? args[number] : match;
    });
}
```

use it like this :

```
 private stopCampaignUrl = '/api/campaign/{0}/activation/';

stopCampaign(uuid, stopModel: StopCampaignModel) {
    return this.http.put(stringFormat(stopCampaignUrl ,uuid), stopModel);
}
```

stringFormat replaces {0} with uuid value . more example :

```
const firstName = "john";
const secondName = "jenny";
stringFormat('hello {0} and {1}',firstName , secondName) // outputs hello john and jenny
```